# How to force matplotlib to use exponent notation in Y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting using plt.plot series with very small numbers, it looks like this.

[image]

Only when the numbers are very small (around 1E-7), it changes to exponential notation : 
[image]

Is there a way to force matplotlib to switch to exponential notation in bigger numbers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`Axes.ticklabel_format()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html). Try this, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.random(100) * 1e5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', scilimits=[-3, 3])
plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image: Example plot]

From the docs:

> **sclimits** — (m, n), pair of integers; if style is 'sci', scientific notation will be used for numbers outside the range 10m to 10n. Use (0,0) to include all numbers. Use (m,m) where m <> 0 to fix the order of magnitude to 10m.